# Python Program to find the neighborhood density of words: NameError: name 'a' is not defined

Tags: python, nlp

I need to create a program that finds words that are orthographical neighbours of the word entered by the user. For instance, the English word good has the word food as its orthographical neighbour because there is only one letter of difference between them. So, I need to find the orthographical neighbour of Portuguese words, i.e., Portuguese words that change from the word entered by the user for 1 letter only. My idea was to loop through a list of letters of the alphabet and replace all the letters of the word entered by the user one by one by the letters of the alphabet and check if the result of each word exists in a dictionary. If so, then the result is appended to a list and displayed by the user. Does that make sense? However, when I run the code below I get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/nataliaresende/Desktop/Book_chapter_Gender_simulation/lexical_neighborhood_porgram.py", line 4, in <module>
    consonants= [a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, l, m, n, o, p, q, r, s, t, u, v, x, y, z, w]
NameError: name 'a' is not defined
```

**So, first I need to know if my code makes sense to achieve my goal, second, I don't understand where's the error. Can anyone help me to achieve my goal?**

```
letters= [a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, l, m, n, o, p, q, r, s, t, u, v, x, y, z, w]
n_words=[]

user=input("Please, enter word: ")

dic=open('Dictionaries/Portuguese_dictionary.txt', 'r')

dic=dic.read().lower()

for i in letters:
    for j in user:
       neighbor=user.replace(i,j)
       if neighbor in dic:
           n_words.append(neighbor)

print(n_words)
```

Comment: This is basically a typo. You have `letters= [a, b, c, ...]`, which refers to the literal names `a`, `b`, `c`, etc. Since you haven't defined anything with those names, this fails. You almost certainly meant to specify the letters as strings, like `letters= ['a', 'b', 'c', ...]`.

Comment: Easier: `letters = list('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz')`

Comment: You can't just do `user.replace(i,j)`, because that replaces ALL `i` with `j`.

Answer (score 0):

One way to cheat at this is to convert the letters to their ASCII values.  That eliminates the need to look up the character in a string.  So, for example:

```
for i in range(len(user)):
    back = chr(ord(user[i])-1)
    fwd = chr(ord(user[i])+1)
    backwd = user[:i] + back + user[i+1:]
    nextwd = user[:i] + fwd + user[i+1:]
    if backwd in dic:
        n_words.append( backwd )
    if nextwd in dic:
        n_words.append( nextwd )
```

Here's an example showing it working.  Here, I let every word pass, since I don't have your dictionary.

```
user = 'fine'

n_words = []
for i in range(len(user)):
    back = chr(ord(user[i])-1)
    fwd = chr(ord(user[i])+1)
    backwd = user[:i] + back + user[i+1:]
    nextwd = user[:i] + fwd + user[i+1:]
    if True: #backwd in dic:
        n_words.append( backwd )
    if True: #nextwd in dic:
        n_words.append( nextwd )

print(n_words)
...
C:\tmp>python x.py
['eine', 'gine', 'fhne', 'fjne', 'fime', 'fioe', 'find', 'finf']
```

Comment: Many thanks for this, but with this program, when I enter the Portuguese word "casa" I get:  casb, cas which are not orthographical neighbours of "casa" because they do not exist and they are not included in the Dic file. With word 'ano' I get 'anp' and 'ann'.  So the program is replacing  the last character of the word by the next character in the alphabet and also the previous character. This is not what I'm trying to do. I need a program that replaces all characters one by one to find the orthographical neighbour and check each result in the dictionary.

Comment: You must not have tried my code, because it does exactly what you said.